# Is this question appropriate? Flawed Proof of Green-Tao.

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/puzzle-a-strange-proof-of-the-green-tao-theorem) has attracted a long comment thread. And there is some disagreement about whether it is an appropriate question on this website. This is the spillover discussion question to prevent further cluttering of the main page.

Answer (score 11):

At -7 and 4 close votes, I would say the community is rejecting that question very thoroughly.  So I think anyone defending it would have to provide some pros for keeping it.

Comment: @Jeff: as always, "problem" postings really are indicators of structural improvements for the site.  If in the Questions list, the question rating were followed (e.g., in much smaller font) by the ratings of the top few answers, which functioned as links for those answers, this would address the divergence between negative vote on the questions and high votes on the answers. For example, a -17+4 downvote on a question was followed by 21+6+4 upvotes, and no downvotes, on the answers ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/ ), so perhaps some way of making those visible is in order.

Comment: @T.. you can click the score itself to see the breakdown if you have 1000 or more reputation

Comment: @Jeff: yes, I used that (note the +17 - 4 ).  I meant that it is of interest when selecting what to read, to know if the individual *answers* to a question got high votes.  Right now the Questions list tells only the vote count on a question.  This would be very useful for all questions, but for the present discussion, the point was that there are negative-voted questions with highly upvoted answers and there one wants to disaggregate the visibility of the question from that of the answer.

Comment: @T.. the answer scores are used in the hot tab calculation, however -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Comment: That's good to know. But the instances of question/answer vote decorrelation (as well as stupendous answers on subjects one might not ordinarily read) are exactly why this feature would, IMO, be *extremely* useful, especially with the ability to zoom in directly on the quality answers.

Comment: @T.. Could you explain in more detail why the hot tab doesn't satisfy your needs? My understanding of what Jeff just said is that answers with lots of up votes will push the question up on that tab. To "zoom in on the quality answers" is hard to make any easier than in the current implementation: you just have to find the end of the question (most people will want to read the question anyway, before they read the quality answers).

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure what the snide phrase "satisfy your needs" refers to. I indicated an opportunity for improvement, not a deficit.  The implications of the formula are not as clear as you say. In the example I linked, the ((Qvotes)*(Qanswer) + (Ascore)) in Jeff's formula is *negative*,  so the question downvotes will *suppress* the 21-upvote, 0-downvote answer.  Seeing those outliers, as well as massively upvoted answers in average-voted questions on subjects one doesn't normally read, and the extra information from the answer vote-counts, seems like a good use of 10 small-font characters.

Comment: @T.. I really wish that you could relax a bit and stop reading personal attacks and "snide remarks" into my comments, where there are none. I was genuinely curious, where you found the current system wanting (you used the phrase "opportunity for improvement", but I couldn't see one). I still don't quite understand what your proposal for "zooming in on quality answers" entails, since the current system is all about zooming in on the most popular answers already. As for the hot tab, why not modify the hot formula, instead of introducing yet another tab? In any case...

Comment: ..., this proposal will be lost here, in comments to an unrelated answer. I suggest that you open a separate thread for it or argue for a modification of the formula for the hot tab over at the thread linked to by Jeff. That thread seems to have been designed for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @Alex: I think that Jeff understood both the technical discussion and the [meta-feature-request] it is meant to illustrate: use "problem" postings as an opportunity for adding improvements, not restricting discussion.  Concerning the 'zoom' idea it meant that the Questions page include, in some fashion (presumably next to the question ratings), direct links to each of the top few answers per question (presumably with vote counts or other quality indicators such as colored icons etc).  But this is, again, an *illustration* of the actual, and on-topic, request that was made within this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was posted (by the same person) and discussed on Terence Tao's blog, where it received two answers from Terry himself, totalling more than 400 words. This is longer than either of the answers it got in math.SE.

The mathematics Arxiv, the online repository of current research in mathematics, has one percent or more of its content classified as "General Mathematics", which de facto (and pretty much by design) means crackpot papers.  This is higher than the percentage of comparably unorthodox questions that survive on math.SE.  In SE terms, the Arxiv's approach to nonstandard papers is *tagging* instead of closing; what moderators did not wish to evaluate further or classify they tagged as [math.GM] and let the readers decide what, if anything, to make of those works.  Later an endorsement system was added, so the entry barrier got higher and the moderator work distributed to a community, but the principle remains the same that detailed subjective evaluations of content are not required or imposed as a prerequisite to posting.

It is strange that a site populated by ordinary internet users (most of them without Fields Medals) and devoted to questions at all levels (not research) would try to set a stricter standard for content.  This is self-defeating, in my opinion.  Questions that lack a standard mathematical format or outlook can be interesting to ponder, either as mathematics or as a pedagogical or psychological matter of how to explain something to people who lack customary prerequisites or assumptions.  This is in addition to the community editing capabilities to improve postings.

The restrictiveness is not only a problem of thread closings. Questions of the kind discussed in this meta thread are getting excessive numbers of downvotes that don't correlate with the quality of answers elicited.  The site content is mainly in the answers, and some questions are provocative enough to get good answers simply because they *are* unorthodox, wrong or even hostile in relation to accepted ideas.

Comment: I couldn't find this in Tao's blog (I found it was also posted on sci.math). Could you please share a link?

Comment: @Andres: it was in the comment thread under the (amazing) posting "The parity problem in sieve theory". See the question by "Craig" and the answers containing the phrase *argumentam ad ignorantium*.  URL: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/05/open-question-the-parity-problem-in-sieve-theory/

Comment: It *was* interesting to see that Terry took the question seriously enough to respond to it.  (I suppose that if someone had written into my blog claiming a three line proof of the one result that people most associate with my name and my Fields medal, I would be tempted to respond in some way, albeit not necessarily as gracefully as Professor Tao did.)  Unfortunately one can look at this exchange in a different way: the OP asked the question of Terry Tao, got a quite complete answer, and thanked him for his time.  Then *almost a year later* he asks the same question here....

Comment: ...At this point it looks more like an *idee fixe* than a mathematical matter that we here can help out with.  Is anyone here capable and willing of giving a better answer than Professor Tao did at the end of 2009?

Comment: -1: How does it matter if a Fields Medalist had to field the question on his public blog, regarding his own theorem? Did you notice that Terry did claim the proof was nonsense too (in polite words)? Frankly, there was no real mathematical content in Terry's comments (I see only speculation). I did learn some latin, though. As you seem to think, I doubt any lowly, ordinary internet user (sans Field Medal) can do any better. The closure of questions is subjective, and community decides (like in this case). Sometimes, potentially good get rejected. IMO, that is ok: price we pay for good content.

Comment: @Moron: Dear T.. and Moron, I wrote a comment to the question (since it was closed I couldn't post an answer) which the OP seemed to appreciate.  After looking at Terry Tao's blog, it seems to be similar in spirit to the explanation that Terry gave there.  I don't think that it does any harm to provide such explanations.  I completely agree with T..'s assessment that such questions "can be interesting to ponder, either as mathematics or as a pedagogical or psychological matter of how to explain something to people who lack customary prerequisites or assumptions".  In fact I think it's good ...

Comment: ... if a mathematical site like this one, which is likely going to provide a rather significant public face for mathematics as time goes on, does provide such explanations.    I understand that people are concerned that such questions form the thin edge of a wedge, but downvoting helps blunt this edge.  I'm also open to the idea that I'm being too naive, but my (albeit limited) experience on MO and here suggests that a small amount of consideration shown to amateurs like this goes a long way. Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt: While I agree with what you wrote in general, I am not really sure if this(math.SE) is the right forum for questions like these. Any question which requires speculative interpretation, extended discussion etc is off-topic, IMO. Also, if the answers amount to basically, "what you wrote is nonsense, though, here is some speculation of my own", I see no problem in closing those off. The aim is to have a site with specific questions and their answers. If we start allowing questions that are not well-defined etc, the quality of this site will go down pretty quickly, IMO.

Comment: @Matt E: I liked your replies, but they were forced into the comments because the thread was closed.  The closure makes this additional high-quality material less visible (and harder to format and read) for users of the site and disorganizes it as a conversation with the OP.  The moderators are not responsible for this closure but in a sense that is worse: the users themselves are preventing interesting content from getting onto the site.  Absolutely agree with "it's good if a mathematical site like this one ... does provide such explanations".

Comment: @Moron: the professional prize has nothing to do with the level of answer to be expected from a medal-holder compared to a non-medalist. High-status professors have less incentive to spend time on detailed responses and I would expect better answers to simple questions from math.SE than Mathoverflow or the blog of Math God X.  It seems, however, that Tao and other leading mathematicians do not dismiss these questions quite as easily as the math.SE users who are so liberal with the close votes. A more inclusive approach, plus strengthening of the filtering technology, would not hurt.

Comment: @T..: My claim is that Tao was compelled to respond, because it was his public blog and it directly concerned his theorem (and Pete seems to agree). Tao's response basically was that the argument is logically fallacious, I hope you agree. The other point is that such questions, which are of dubious mathematical value, are open ended, are so badly defined to the point of no redemption, are off-topic on math.SE. There might be _some_ mathematical value (don't dispute that), but that is not what this site is about.  It is not as if people here are being closed minded (pun intended :-)), but it...

Comment: ... is really about what is on-topic on math.SE. The questions on this site are as important as answers and we should not encourage questions which are open to wildly speculative interpretation. As Akhil aptly quoted someone, "A good answer does not a good question make".  As to the professional prize, you brought it up :-)

Comment: @Moron: Tao could have deleted or ignored the comment (since it did not claim a proof), given a much shorter answer ("argument is ill-defined starting at the words: ... "), or waited for other readers to answer, as they often do.  If you check the blog you will see that he answers similar elementary confusions in other comment threads not connected to his own work. High-level mathematicians (tenured at top institutions, holders of huge research grants, prizewinners, etc) have answered "bad" or confused questions here and on other forums. They tend to turn "speculative" into "clear".

Comment: @T..: What Tao does or does not or can do, is irrelevant! What is on-topic here or not is. The basic premise of this site is good specific questions with good answers. This site is not the only resource when it comes to Mathematics. Please don't treat it as such. Opening up the doors to questions like these will only serve to pollute the quality content we have. These are usually a big waste of time and might even deprive other quality questions from getting the attention they deserve. I believe sci.math is now dying because of such threads.

Comment: @Moron: sci.math died years ago for unrelated reasons, such as not handling the volume growth with additional groups.  math.SE appears to be in line for that problem, too, given the complexity of forming new groups on Area 51.  Different users have different ideas of what is a good question and there is no need to reach agreement if the site allows users to set, individually, a *quality threshold* (e.g., fewer than 3 downvotes) below which postings are invisible to them.  You could set it higher and I might set it lower, or adjust it at any given time. Technology, not restriction.

Comment: @T..: I would probably agree with you, if this was the _only_ math resource available to anyone. Anyway...